# MySQL compatible data types for DB2

Tags: mysql, ssis, ibm-midrange, type-conversion, db2-400

I am working on creating a SSIS package from DB2 for i to MySQL. Can some one help me in figuring out the right data types to use in MySQL that are compatible with DB2 for i?

Data type in DB2 for i are:

1. 2S
2. 45A

Comment: Don't they have really expensive consultants that figure this sort of stuff out?

Comment: I am not sure what your trying to say

Comment: Although you're free to ask, AS400 is a very specialized thing and I'm not sure you'll get an answer. You may have to experiment and find out yourself. **What have you tried**?

Comment: ok, I am using the Data converter in SSIS.  trying to relate datatypes.  By searching in online I came to know S- numeric/Decimal and A - alphanumeric.

Comment: @tadman - we're not **that** expensive ;-) Though if someone wants to pay me a lot of money to answer questions like this I'm definitely available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `2S` means "signed" numeric. There should be another number following the `2S` and that will signify the number of decimal positions. If that other number is a 0 you can use any of the integer types in MySQL: `tinyint`, `smallint`, etc. If that other number is not a zero you can use `float` in MySQL.

The `45A` means 45 alphanumeric characters. The MySQL equivalent would be `char(45)` (though you'll want to use `varchar(45)`).